# Need Algorithm to generate contour by TIN in GIS

Tags: c#, gis

I want to draw contour in GIS by using X,Y and Z value.Please suggest a general Algorithm for the construction of Contour by using TIN(Triangulated Irregular Network).Contour could be line contour or color contour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways for creation of Contours. Providing you a link which will help you in understanding the whole concept of creation of contours using TIN (Triangulated Irregular Network)

Here is a link: https://www.e-education.psu.edu/natureofgeoinfo/book/export/html/1833

Answer (score 1):

try this algorithm to draw contour lines:

http://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/Create-Contour-Graph